# How can I export Wordpress site's data (specially users and comments) to a CMS/board built from scratch?

Tags: wordpress, migration

I'm going to create a personal CMS/board for a website. Currently the site is using Wordpress so, more specifically, how can I export all the users and comments from Wordpress to a self-build website? Is it possible to make this big change without losing anything?

Comment: It's all in the database which you have access to. You only lose what you fail to export.

Comment: Have you looked into getting the data out of a database backup?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database   There are also WordPress plugins that will export data in various formats: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users are located in the wp_users table. Your posts are located in the wp_posts table and your comments are located in the wp_comments table. Simply export these tables with the tool of your choice and all that remains is to normalize the columns and ID numbers for import into the new system.